# Can I access a variable I declared in a js file in different js file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to export this js file.

```
const student =
{
    studentID : 1,
}
export {student}
```

this is my second file in which I'm trying to import it.

```
import {student} from "./studentId";
console.log(student);
```

It's not importing it and **throwing this error**.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message. You are getting a 404 Not Found error.

Node.js does not need a file extension when loading a module. It has access to the file system and can look at all the files in a directory.

Web browsers do not have any way of telling if the URL you specified should have a `.js` or `.jsx` or `.mjs` or `.tsx` or whatever extension added to it.

You need to specify the **actual URL** you are importing.

```
 import {student} from "./studentId.js";
```